# $scope.$apply() on a single $scope property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to tell Angular 1.6 to do dirty checking on only one property?

For example, I call:

```
 $scope.unansweredCount++;
 $scope.$apply();
```

instead, I am wondering if we can do this:

```
 $scope.unansweredCount++;
 $scope.$apply('unansweredCount');
```

or whatever. That way Angular doesn't have to check everything for changes, just one property.

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: short answer is ..No. Keep components small as is practical

Comment: no, but you can use one time binding to bind properties that you don't want to watch.....

Comment: @charlietfl I guess you mean controllers when you say components?